# Parsing pipe separated strings with no values in between for some cases

Tags: java

I am trying to parse a file containing pipe separated strings, which should have 8 columns in it. But in some cases, there are less columns than expected. In such cases, I am getting an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`, as the array size is less than what I expected.

How to handle this? I always want to have the same array length and with blank values, if there are no data.

**Sample Data:**

In the example data below, the first line works fine as expected, but the other 3 fail.

```
1-chloro-4-nitrobenzene|100-00-5||157.553 |NO2C6H4Cl||400|FID1GC/MSGCMS
geranyl butyrate|106-29-6||224.34|C14H24O2|||
4’-methoxyacetophenone|100-06-1||150.18|C9H10O2|||
p-Anisic Acid|100-09-4|152.047|152.149|C8H8O3||400|
```

**Results**

```
Invalid: column size : [5], line : geranyl butyrate|106-29-6||224.34|C14H24O2|||
Invalid: column size : [5], line : 4’-methoxyacetophenone|100-06-1||150.18|C9H10O2|||
Invalid: column size : [7], line : p-Anisic Acid|100-09-4|152.047|152.149|C8H8O3||400|
```

**Java Code**

```
     @Test
    public void testComponentsFileParsing3() {

        String fileName = "src/main/resources/admin/bulkupload_by_api/comp.txt";

        BufferedReader reader = null;
        try {

            reader = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get(fileName));
            String line = null;

            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {

                String columns[] = line.split(Pattern.quote("|"));
                //String columns[] = StringUtils.split(line,"\\|");
                //String columns[] = line.split("\\|");

                String description = null;
                String code = null; // code & cas number are same
                String casNumber = null; // code & cas number are same
                String accurateMass = null;
                String molecularWeight = null;
                String molecularFormula = null;
                String ozoneDepletingSubstance = null;
                int estimatedShelfLife = 0;
                String technique = null;


                try {
                    description = columns[0];
                    code = columns[1]; // code & cas number are same
                    casNumber = columns[1]; // code & cas number are same
                    accurateMass = columns[2];
                    molecularWeight = columns[3];
                    molecularFormula = columns[4];
                    ozoneDepletingSubstance = columns[5];
                    estimatedShelfLife = NumberUtils.toInt(columns[6]);
                    technique = columns[7];

                } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException ae) {
                    System.out.println("Invalid: column size : [" + columns.length + "], line : " + line);
                    continue;
                }
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is expected as per [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)):

> This method works as if by invoking the two-argument split method with the given expression and a limit argument of zero. Trailing empty strings are therefore not included in the resulting array.

You could call the [two-argument variant](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String,%20int)) with limit = `-1` to have all the trailing empty elements included in the result, or possibly with limit = `8` (or whatever your expected column count is) if that suits your case better.

Either way, you should probably check the actual array length afterwards to catch any erroneous inputs.